# Invalied token error in google calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using google calendar api to addd events tocalendar. When I'm using oauth2.0, its asking for oauth and working properly. but after 2 0r 3 try, its failing, it shows invalied token error. And again after some times it work properly.
And if I use the token stored, its asking for oauth2 for the first 1 or 2 attempts and its fine. but its not asking for oauth and no events are being created. agin after some tries its asking for oauth2.
I didn't get any Idea why its happening so. Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.  With out seeing your code we have no way of helping you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably occurring because your tokens are expiring. Include access=offline and prompt=consent in the authorization code link and it will probably start to work. Also make sure to refresh your token of the original access token fails and call the API with the new access token.

I work with Pathfix and it takes off the exact hassle for you if you want to save some time with the OAuth dance :)

Comment: thank you, but the issue is only in one server. in all other servers with apache its working. Is there any chance of failure when using 2 servers for the same project like clustering or load balancing?

Comment: I would need some more info to help with your question. Are the tokens stored in memory cache??